# How does SQL Server maintain connections?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Does SQL Server 2005 create one thread per connection? or How does it manage connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it has a pool of threads, which get created or terminated as necessary.  Connections are managed separately from worker threads that do the actual query execution.  A query can also result in more than one thread being used for parallel execution plans.

Some older unix-based DB's, such as Informix SE or older versions of Postgres would fork a single process per connection, maintaining shared data structures by attaching to a shared memory pool.  Oracle can also work in 'Shared Server' mode, which (IIRC) also works this way.

The third book in the ['Guru's Guide'](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=henderson+gurus+guide&x=0&y=0) series has a detailed look at the internal architecture of SQL Server 2000; in most respects SQL Server 2005 is not significantly different.  Amongst other things, this discusses thread management.  As a bonus, the first half of the book has a good overview of key aspects of Win32 systems programming, presented as a backgrounder for the architectural review of the database server.